# AJAX filter MySQL results using checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm attempting to get to grips with displaying filterable MySQL data within a PHP page based on user checkbox selections. I have a database of domain names and the dates on which these will require renewal as per Nominet DAC information and I can get unfiltered data to display, but filtering results by domain extensions is proving tricky for me to accomplish. I should point out at this stage that I am a serious newcomer to many of the ideas I am trying to learn to work with here, so please be gentle. I have tried following some other articles on here also, but no dice.

I have the following so far:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="extensions" name="extensions" value=".co.uk">.co.uk</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="extensions" name="extensions" value=".org.uk">.org.uk</input>
```

Script

```
$('.extensions').live('click', function() {
var all_boxes = $('.extensions');
var all_boxes_values = [];
var i = 0;
for (var i; i < all_boxes.length; i++) {
    if (all_boxes[i].checked) {
        all_boxes_values.push(all_boxes[i].value)
    }
}   
var all_boxes_values_clean = all_boxes_values.join(", ");
console.log(all_boxes_values_clean);
$.get("sql-test.php", {q: all_boxes_values_clean},
function(result) {
$("div#output").html(result);
}   
    )});
```

PHP

```
$g = $_GET['q'];
$extensionsql="";
$extension=1;
if(isset($g))   {
$extension=1;
$param = "" . str_replace(",", "','", $_GET['q']) . "";
}
```

And that's as far as I have gotten with my limited ability. What I would like to do next is search the column domainName for a string match and return the appropriate results to the user. Something to mimic something like the following but I'm not sure how to achieve it. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
SELECT * FROM `refresh` WHERE `domainName` LIKE '%.co.uk%' AND renewalDate LIKE '%2012-06-30%' ORDER BY `domainName` ASC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

change name="extensions" to name="extensions[]" as this will create an array of elements, not overwrite with the last checked value (IF YOU POST IT NORMALLY)

AND

```
$g = explode(',', $_GET['q']);

$param='';
while(list($key,$value)=each($g))
{
    $param.="`domainName` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' OR ";
}
$param=substr($param,-3); // knock off last OR

$sql="SELECT * FROM `refresh` WHERE renewalDate LIKE '%2012-06-30%' AND (".$param.") ORDER BY `domainName` ASC
```

Comment: +1, but `while(list($key,$value)=each($g))` is so early php 4 era, dude. Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :)

Comment: Thanks @Waygood. I have converted the while(list... to a foreach now, but the script returns a SQL error when run: OR You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR ) ORDER BY domainName ASC' at line 1. Are you able to advise as to why this would be the case? Thanks again so much for your help on this

Answer (score 1):

Change name of checkboxes (extensions[]) to make them arrays when POSTed back to PHP:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="extensions" name="extensions[]" value=".co.uk">.co.uk</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="extensions" name="extensions[]" value=".org.uk">.org.uk</input>
```

Probably should clean up your javascript a bit:

```
$('.extensions').live('click', function() {
var all_boxes = $('.extensions');
var checked_boxes = $('.extensions:checked');
var all_boxes_values = [];

checked_boxes.each(function(){
 var cb_value = $(this).val();
 all_boxes_values.push(cb_value);
});

var all_boxes_values_clean = all_boxes_values.join(", ");
console.log(all_boxes_values_clean);
$.get("sql-test.php", {q: all_boxes_values_clean},
      function(result) {
       $("div#output").html(result);
      })
});
```

Comment: Thanks @David for the code cleanup. Way better than my amateurish attempts :)